# Why wouldn't the PC take the bishop?

Tags: computer-chess

In this scenario, I do not understand why the computer did not do Bxa6.

There could be an argument that he did not want to exchange the pieces, if white follows with Nxa6, but if he does not take the bishop, then in the next turn, white can make Bxa7, making his lose the Bishop for nothing.

What could be the rationale behind this? Only a REALLY dumb bot??

[image]

**UPDATE:** I updated the image, because I uploaded a wrong one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're playing an engine "rated" 600. It is programmed to play many awful moves.

Here, technically on Bxa6 we have Qa5 and the bishop is pinned to the rook so you're regaining the piece. Nxa6 is coming next. But of course the tactics there continue: O-O! and on Nxa6 black has Rfa8! and once again it is white who is losing the original piece. All of this is way above a 600 level player.

The point still stands though. This bot will play many seemingly random moves that hang a piece (or don't capture a free piece) just to emulate 600 level play.

Comment: Sorry, I updated hte image! Thanks!

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent updated the answer